# Remove detailPanel based in condition causes padding

Tags: html, css, material-ui, material-table

Everyone, I'm trying to add `detailPanel` based in a condition, it leaves a space when I hide it like this 
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvFwI.png)

And This Code works fine when I provide `detail panel`

```
get rowDetailsPanel() {
const { detailPanel, classes } = this.props;
// @Workarround To Hide Details Panel In Case There is No Details Panels Provided
return [
  {
    tooltip: 'Show Name',
    disabled: !detailPanel,
    icon: () => <ChevronRightIcon className={!detailPanel && classes.displayNone}/>,
    render: rowData => detailPanel(rowData)
  },
];
```

}

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5k2p.png) for working `detailPanel`,

So what I'm trying to do is when I hide the `detailPanel`, I **want to delete the whole column**

Any clue will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
get rowDetailsPanel() {
const { detailPanel, classes } = this.props;
// @Workarround To Hide Details Panel In Case There is No Details Panels Provided
return detailPanel ? [
  {
    tooltip: 'Show Name',
    disabled: !detailPanel,
    icon: () => <ChevronRightIcon className={!detailPanel && classes.displayNone}/>,
    render: rowData => detailPanel(rowData)
  },
] : undefined;
```